# Is data fusion suitable for this application?

Tags: dataset, inference

I have a situation where the delay vehicles experience at an intersection can be obtained through 3 or 4 types of sensors. Each sensor provides its own type of data with their own unique characteristics which all have different types errors/outliers (compared to ground truth data) associated with them. Also, the data is only being collected for a portion of the vehicles passing by. So for example for delay estimation in 5 minute intervals we may have data from 2 of these sensors or 1 or in some cases many records from all the sensors. I am conducting this project in a simulation environment so I exactly know what the ground truth values are at any point. I have been able to develop models using the data obtained from each sensor separately for estimating the delay. However, I am thinking about somehow "fusing" these data sources together for improved estimations. Are data fusion techniques suitable for this application? Do you know of any software packages that could help me out on this? 
What other methods do you suggest in tackling this problem?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks In Advance